# How to use document.elementFromPoint() relative to parent element instead of document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that I am trying to get the id of an element using its position by using jquery, and I have only found document.elementFromPoint() method, however this method get the element by its position relative to the document.

What I want is to get the element by its position relative to the parent.. How do I achieve this ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Get the parent’s position within the document, and then use that to calculate what position in the document you have to query for …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getElementByPoint( parent, x, y ) {
    if ( x < parent.width() && y < parent.height() ) {
        return document.elementFromPoint( x + parent.offset().left, y + parent.offset().top );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`getElementByPoint( jQuery('#parent'), 100, 50 );`

Comment: elementFromPoint get's the element at specified position relative to the viewport, not the document.